# Nikon D800E: How does Image Quality compare between PC-E Lenses or Medium Format lenses (via adapter) for Tilt/Shift?

Tags: nikon, tilt-shift, zeiss, hasselblad

I have a Nikon D800E and want to have shift/tilt. I am mainly focused on having shift, because I want to stitch photos to get broader ratios without cropping.

I am considering two options:

- Nikon PC-E lenses, which are very expensive (about 1500 Euro, I would buy the 45mm and the 85mm)
- a Mirex adapter and Hasselblad Zeiss lenses (thinking of the Zeiss Makro Planar CF 120mm and the 50mm CF Distagon)

From what I have read online, opinions about the image quality (resolution, sharpness) of medium format lenses on full-frame DSLR vary. Would medium format Hasselblad or Zeiss lenses on an adapter be good enough to compete with the PC-E lenses on a full-frame DSLR?

Comment: Have you considered doing this in software?

Comment: @Unapiedra - Tilt/shift perspective correction is going to be better than doing it in post.

Comment: JoanneC: You're still going to have to stitch the multiple images taken with the shift at various positions together. Scroll down about 3/4 of the way to see the composite from 12 frames shifted in each direction. http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-TS-E-24mm-f-3.5-L-II-Tilt-Shift-Lens-Review.aspx

Comment: Regarding tilt/shift in optics vs software, I still need to do the test but the center/edge sharpness of a TS lens *with no tilt/shift* should be significantly higher than the edge sharpness with tilt/shift such that its entirely possible doing it in post could be sharper, certainly on a D800(e).

Comment: @MichaelClark - Sure, but I still think it's better to minimize the amount of software correction.

Comment: He doesn't want to use tilt at all. I don't understand what software correction everyone is talking about. He wants to use the shift feature in each direction and then stitch together the resulting photos to increase the FoV for a given focal length without increasing the sensor size and without giving up the resolution he would sacrifice if he used a wider lens and cropped the 3:2 result to get the aspect ratio he wants.

Answer (score 3):

Not a comparative answer, but Nikon has their current-generation PC-E lenses on their "recommended" list for the D800 in the [Technical Solutions](http://nps.nikonimaging.com/technical_solutions/d800_d800e_tips/d800e/) document. According to Nikon, the subset of lenses in this list offer maximum resolution of all the lenses they make. In other words, they are a top-notch choice.

(To be honest, though, I also wonder if this list simply includes the newest and most expensive lenses to get users to spend more money.)

Comment: Of course they do... I'm sure that when I bought the 70-300mm f4-5.6 to put on my D800 there were screams of anguish. :D